# ConcurentModificationException in Java HashMap

Tags: java, concurrency, thread-safety, hashmap

Suppose I have two methods in my classes, `writeToMap()` and `processKey()` and both methods are called by multiple threads. `writeToMap` is a method to write something in hashmap and `processKey()` is used to do sth based on the `keySet` of `HashMap`.

Inside processKey, I first copy the `originalMap` before getting the key set.

```
new HashMap<String, Map<String,String>(originalMap).get("xx").keySet();
```

But I am still getting `ConcurrentModificationException` even though I always copy the hashmap. Whats the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The copy constructor of HashMap performs a (hidden) [iteration](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/HashMap.java#HashMap.putAllForCreate%28java.util.Map%29) on the map that is being copied (originalMap). If originalMap is modified by another thread while this iteration is in progress, you may get a ConcurrentModificationException.

Comment: The most straightforward solution is to use a thread-safe map for the original map. You can use ConcurrentHashMap for example. Then you do not need to create a copy. Also, note that since values are maps themselves they need to be thread safe as well if they are accessed and modified concurrently.

Comment: I am wondering is ConcurrentHashMap really solving the problem. From my unserstanding, ConcurrentHashMap just make sure get and put is atomic.

Comment: Iterations are thread safe too (as long as you don't pass iterators around different threads).

Answer (score 2):

You have nested maps, and you are copying the outer map, before getting the inner map from it.  Notice that the inner map has not been copied, so when you iterate over it, you're still using a shared data structure.

Hard to say based on the short snippet of code, but I think you don't need to copy the outer map, and you do need to copy the inner map.